# How do I upload a file to an FTP server through SOCKS proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, ftp, socks

I've been successfully uploading files to my FTP server using the following code.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS");
    client.UploadFile("ftp://adress/" + filename, "STOR", file);
}
```

However, this does not work with a firewall protected network.
The connection must go through a SOCKS proxy in order to bypass the firewall.

How can this be done?
How can I use third party libraries like http://mentalis.org/ or any other library to establish a connection to a SOCKS proxy and upload files to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET framework FTP clients (`FtpWebRequest` or `WebClient`) cannot connect using SOCKS proxy, only [HTTP [download only] and ISA client proxies are supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.proxy):

> The FtpWebRequest class supports HTTP and ISA Firewall Client proxies.
>
> If the specified proxy is an HTTP proxy, only the DownloadFile, ListDirectory, and ListDirectoryDetails commands are supported.

So you need to use a 3rd party FTP library.

---

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), you can use:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

// Configure proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyMethod", "2"); // SOCKS5 proxy
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("ProxyHost", "proxy");

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Your code
}
```

For the options for the [`SessionOptions.AddRawSettings`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions_addrawsettings), see [raw settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings).

Easier is to have WinSCP GUI [generate C# FTP code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.

Note that WinSCP .NET assembly is not a native .NET library. It's rather a thin .NET wrapper over a console application.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I have managed to upload a file using your library, but I didn't use a proxy. I realised that there aren't many good socks5 proxies for free. Is it possible to use the tor network?

Comment: No, tor is not supported. And that's a different question anyway.

Comment: +1 for the Connection Code generator that supports multiple languages (thought I would have to translate the C# but I didn't)